# How to overlap with a semi-transparent layer in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, transparency

Layer 1:

[image]

Layer 2:

[image]

Layers Combined (giving Layer 1 a white outline):

[image]

Buggy Final Product (because Layer 1 has a white outline as opposed to the desired overlapping transparent outline):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the stroke to outlines and then subtract the expanded outline from the image in the back